# How to make this design in using css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make this design but could n't get any success ? I am not getting to overcome this issue Any help would be appreciable

I am attaching the image for the design I wanted

[image]

Here is my code that I have tried

```css
.auth__container {
    min-height: 70%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 2rem;
    border-radius: .4rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.auth__nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding: 0;
    background: #e8e6e6;
    width: 50%;
    
}

.auth__nav-heading {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #e42a70;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: -1rem;
    height: 4rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.auth__nav-heading:before {
    border-width: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
    border-color: transparent blue;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul class="auth__nav"><li class="auth__nav-item auth__nav-heading">Sign up</li><li class="auth__nav-item">Login</li></ul>
```

I wanted the border bottom should be pointed like in the image I have marked but I am not getting it, Can anyone help me out with this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve using a css triangle `#triangle` wich has a `position: absolute`:

```css
.auth__container {
    min-height: 70%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 2rem;
    border-radius: .4rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.auth__nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding: 0;
    background: #e8e6e6;
    width: 50%;
    
}

.auth__nav-heading {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #e42a70;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: -1rem;
    height: 4rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.auth__nav-heading:before {
    border-width: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
    border-color: transparent blue;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -1rem;
}  

#triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
  border-color: transparent #e42a70 transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul class="auth__nav">
  <li class="auth__nav-item auth__nav-heading"><span id="triangle"></span>Sign up</li>
  <li class="auth__nav-item">Login</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Ronak07 Not a problem. Please `upvote` **all** usefulls answers Thanks ;)

Comment: Already did @johannchopin :)

Answer (score 0):

With this html

```
<div class="ph">
  <div class="ph-left">
    <div></div><div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ph-right">
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this css

```
.ph {
  display: flex;
}
.ph * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ph-left {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 35px;
}
.ph-left div:first-child {
  margin-top: 150px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
}
.ph-left div:last-child {
  width: 35px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-right: 35px solid red;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}
.ph-right {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 360px;
  width: 360px;
}
.ph-right img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
}
.ph-right h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 0;
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

You get this image with banner

[image: Photo with banner]